# MERGE data in a Dataflow of Azure Data Factory into an existing table

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a DataFlow under Azure Data Factory that inserts & updates rows into a table after performing some transformations. When I am trying to write the modified data into a 'Sink' I am selecting both checkboxes, 'Allow Inserts' & 'Allow Updates'. A message pops up telling me to create 'Add Alter Row'. What I want to do is simply update if the primary columns match; otherwise insert rows but I cannot figure out how to do that under 'Add Alter Row'.

To summarize, I want to write all the rows back to the table. If PK columns match then update row; otherwise insert row. How do I do that? Unfortunately, truncating the table is not a solution I can use.

Essentially, I need to perform a 'MERGE'.

Comment: Alter Row only filter the data from Source dataset. I have some ideas, create a store proc in the database, then using copy active to copy the data from your source dataset as parameters,  call the stored proc in Sink dataset. All you needed is to think about how to design the stored proc.

Comment: I am hoping to do this without writing a Stored Proc. I can always write the updates into a Staging table & update from there using a stored proc but is there no way to simply update using matching keys?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solve it and it works. I will merge my two tables `TEST2` and `TEST3`, all the rows will write to `TEST3`.

Data in my table `TEST2` and `TEST3`:

[image]

**Here's my Data FLOW**:
[image]

[image]

**Firstly, using JOIN to get the data from `TEST2` and `TEST3`**:

[image]
[image]

**Alter Row settings and Data Preview:**

[image]

[image]

**Sink settings and Data Preview:**

[image]
[image]

**Check the data in TEST3:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this. Question! Wondering why you used 'sql' as a column name in one table & 'name' in the other. Usually the staging table (TEST2) & target table (TEST3) columns would be same. Were you trying to save a 'Select' step?

Comment: Anyway, thanks to your tips I was able to get it working. I had to add an extra Join condition. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I just use the exist tables for the test. They have different column name but the same schema.

Comment: Quick question. My pipeline/dataflow is working but everything is hard coded to work with only one table. All column names are hard coded etc. Now I want to generalize this process. Make this pipeline/dataflow work with 100 other tables. I know I can use Parameters etc but how do I dynamically/programmatically generate a dataflow... hopefully using Java? I don't see any Java APIs. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't answer you. Just according my knowledge and experience, it's really hard for me. I  don't think Data Factory/Data flow is good at doing very complex data processing .

Comment: To generalize your pattern, use parameters and pipeline mechanisms. You can also use patterns inside of data flows as opposed to using direct column references.

Comment: If you still wish to "stamp-out" a number of different versions of the same pattern, you can do so with the ADF API. You'll just need to modify the data flow script behind the transformations that have the direct table and column references.

Comment: Here are the API refs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ (look under References)

Comment: And here are sample generic patterns in data flows: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/create-generic-scd-pattern-in-adf-mapping-data-flows/ba-p/918519

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sj15Yjwai1A

Comment: If you want to merge CSV files instead, watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WbDTBAyYte8